# trying to look for duplicates in an ordered list

Tags: python-3.x

So my programs function is to add the provided numbers to an ordered list, then search for the duplicates. I have a function that finds the duplicates of a number I asked and I know is a duplicate. Im trying to get the duplic function to read through the list and append the duplicates to a new list called seen.

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self,initdata):
       self.data = initdata
       self.next = None
   def getData(self):
       return self.data
   def getNext(self):
       return self.next
   def setNext(self,newnext):
       self.next = newnext

class OrderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, item):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        stop = False
        while current != None and not stop: 
           if current.getData() > item:
            stop = True
           else:
               previous = current
               current = current.getNext()

        temp = Node(item)
        if previous == None:
            temp.setNext(self.head)
            self.head = temp
        else:
            temp.setNext (current)
            previous.setNext(temp)

   def prntlist(self):
       prnt = self.head
       while prnt != None:
          print(prnt.data, end=" ")
          prnt = prnt.next
       print()

   def duplic (self):
       currnt = self.head
       seen = set()
       uniq = []
       for i in range(int(currnt.data)):
           if i not in seen:
              uniq.append(i)
              seen.add(i)
       print (seen)


    def count(self, item):# function to count the value
        count = 0
        ptr = self.head
        while ptr != None:
          if (ptr.data == item):
              count += 1
          ptr = ptr.next
        return count

mylist = OrderedList()
mylist.add(23)
mylist.add(23)
mylist.add(10)
mylist.add(14)
mylist.add(5)
mylist.add(31)
mylist.add(35)
mylist.add(37)
mylist.add(26)
mylist.add(23)
mylist.add(29)
mylist.add(18)
mylist.add(2)
mylist.add(25)
mylist.prntlist()



print('Count of 23 in list: ', mylist.count(23))
print('Duplicates in list: ', mylist.duplic())
```

I would like it to print:
mylist
Count of 23 in list: 3
Duplicates in list: {23,23}

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of you class methods? And can you provide a working example of input-output you expect, that would help answering your question.

Comment: oh sorry about that i didnt see that got messed up when posted, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You may need to be more clear in the question..

From what i understand, you could write the function this way:

```
def duplic (self):
       currnt = self.head
       seen = set()
       for i in currnt.data:
           if currnt.data.count(i)>1:
               seen.add(i)
       print (seen)
```

The `uniq` seems to be useless. And, a `set` object cannot have two same elements, so you can't have `{23,23}`. (you can write this, but it will result in `{23}` in the end)

Comment: when I use that function I get this error: line 56, in duplic
    for i in currnt.data:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>>

Comment: @Sailorjoey i think your question is a bit abstract, you may need to be more clear about the variables in your code..

Comment: @Sailorjoey i think your question is a bit abstract, you may need to be more clear about the variables in your code..